# Where to buy a hydration pack / reservoir / bladder / camel bag in Phnom Penh, Cambodia?

Tags: gear, shopping, hiking, cambodia, phnom-penh

A friend of mine I met at my hostel in Phnom Penh who does a lot of walking and hitchhiking wants to buy one of those devices that contain water in a special bladder in your pack or attached to it that you drink through a kind of tube hands-free.

Apparently they are known under various names and brand names of which the Camel Pack or Camel Bag type is used by the US army.

[The Wikipedia page uses the term "hydration pack".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydration_pack) Here's a couple of examples straight from that page.

[image: hydration pack #1] [image: hydration pack #2]

This is probably very specialized for a developing country so is hard to find and would most likely be in some kind of upmarket outdoors shop used mainly by expats and well-off westernised locals I am assuming.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this thread on a dedicated forum](http://www.khmer440.com/chat_forum/viewtopic.php?t=35021#p476198) there's a bike shop called Flying Bikes in Phnom Penh that should sell Hydrapacks's.

> Flying Bikes sell Hydrapaks - as good as a camelbak.

A quick search on Google maps reveals that there are two homonymous shops with incremental names. I'm not sure if they are part of the same franchise though. [Here is Flying Bikes 2](http://goo.gl/maps/npRrF). The other Flying Bikes is not that far north of it.

Comment: Great news, it's our plan to go there tomorrow. Though from today's trip by the airport looking for a place called *Camper* we've learned that Google Maps is riddled with miles-out errors in Phnom Penh.

Comment: @hippietrail Best of luck then. :)

Comment: It turns out one of the Flying Bikes shps does motorcycles and the other does bicycles.

Comment: @hippietrail And neither of them sold bladders?

Comment: As in user26886's answer, the bicycle one did but only had a lower quality smaller bladder but a couple of higher quality packs to choose from. The expat owner there told us the motorbike shop wouldn't have them but he helped us to find the other shops of which Giant had the best range of all shops.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to find a couple of shops which had "hydration bladders" as well as "hydration packs", all of them were westernised bicycle shops with a wide range of  accessories.

- **Flying Bikes 2** had a good quality 1 liter bladder for 23 USD and a lower quality 2 liter for 18 USD.
  [image: Flying Bikes 2] [image: hydration products]
- On street 182 between Bd. Charles De Gaulle and Monivong Bd. there was a **"Scott"** shop with a lot of accessories but they were out of stock.
- On street 294 between Monivong Bd. and Sothearos there was a **"Giant"** retailer with a 2 liter bladder of the same brand for 28 USD which I bought.
  [image: Giant] [image: hydration products]